# This question should not be a review audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73313854/6699433) which I don't think is very suitable as a review audit. I might add that I did pass the audit, so I'm not mad because of a failure. ;)

But there are two things with it that often attracts downvotes:

1. It is a very basic question. At least on the surface. Sure, it has some complex things around it, but it basically boils down to "Why cannot I use a function before it's declared?"
2. It does not contain the compiler error.

I don't think it's a bad question. I actually think it's quite good, and I did upvote it. But with respect to my two points, I think it should be removed as an audit.

EDIT:

This question is based on a false premise. Apparently, there is no way for a moderator to directly prevent a post from appearing as an audit.

Comment: You mean a ["first questions" audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/32545037)?

Comment: @francescalus Well, that's where I found it, but I don't think it's a very good triage audit either.

Comment: Re attracting downvotes: if users feel that the question is very basic, or the fact that it does not contain a compiler error justifies downvoting it, they're welcome to do so. In fact, the OP has shown no attempt whatsoever at solving the problem themselves, which is a popular reason to downvote, apparently. But from the point of view of a review, I think it's fine. As you mention, it's a good question, and if users fail it I think they should just review more carefully.

Comment: @cigien Well, since a DV is one way to fail an audit...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is a question which is open, upvoted and it thrived.  So since audits are automatically picked based on criteria... what can be done here so that this question is not picked as an audit?

Comment: @Gimby AFIK the mods can mark a question to not be used as audit

Comment: Can anyone confirm that? Because based on previous meta posts about fixing audits that isn't the case. The criteria need to be changed instead. That being said, it is kind of amazing that a really basic C++ question was this well-received. But I guess that actually makes it a good audit question, because that anomaly should trigger you to investigate rather than just hit a button.

Comment: @Gimby My assumtions was false

Answer (score 12):

I think this is fine as a review audit. The question is clear and focused, and is about programming (i.e. not closeable).

> It is a very basic question. At least on the surface. Sure, it has some complex things around it, but it basically boils down to "Why cannot I use a function before it's declared?"

Basic questions are still very much on-topic here, provided they're focused and clear.

> It does not contain the compiler error.

This is a fair criticism, but the post author did include this in the form of [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73313854/#comment129473773_73313854). I've submitted [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73313854/3) to include this information so that the question is a bit more completely detailed and flagged the related comments about the compiler error as no longer needed. I feel that's something you could've done too. However, this doesn't necessarily make this a bad candidate for an audit. Submitting an edit would've been an acceptable action during the audit as well, as making good questions better is always encouraged.

I don't see any reason to perform any action in review for this question other than "Looks OK" or maybe even casting an upvote. It seems that 11 other users felt the same way, as per [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73313854/timeline), 11 other users were served this as a First Questions audit and **all of them passed**.

Comment: I noticed an interesting thing. I tried to compile the code with g++, and I got a completely different error message.

Comment: Hahaha, and I got the same review again after your edit :D

Comment: @klutt That looks like an MSVC error message. It's not very good, I agree, although GCC does say the same thing in a note- "note:   candidate expects at least 1 argument, 0 provided". https://godbolt.org/z/KjjeeWz9b

Comment: @cigien This is the error message I got. Completely nonsense https://pastebin.com/ikFzAATk

Comment: @klutt I don't think you've posted the right link. The code there is completely different, and the error is appropriate for that code.

Comment: @cigien https://pastebin.com/HAcquf7v

Comment: @klutt You've `cat`ted "k.cpp", but are compiling "k.c". This is not particularly relevant to the meta post, but using godbolt, or any online compiler, avoids typos like that.

Comment: @cigien Ah, thanks, haha. Oh boy, do I feel stupid now?